# failed to load resource while updating data from widget

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Recently moved wordpress from one host to another. After that unable to add new widget or unable to update script. I need to add new widget to put my script . But showing error in console.

Failed to load resource https://www.name.com/blog/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 403

But file exists in the path.I changed file permission 777 . but its not working

Comment: define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); add this line in wp-config.php file

Comment: i added code . But not working for me same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error 403 caused by below reasons:

**1. Plugins:**
temporarily deactivate all the plugins includes any security plugins that you may have installed on your site. activate all plugins one by one and you can figure out which plugin was causing the error.

**2. Corrupt .htaccess:**
Download the .htaccess file to your computer so that you have a backup of it. After that, you need to delete the file from your server. You can generate new .htaccess file from your WordPress admin area, go to `Settings -> Permalinks` page and just save the changes.

**3. Wrong File Permissions:**
All folders on your WordPress site should have a file permission of 744 or 755. and All files should have a file permission of 644 or 640.

If all things are correct on your website, ask your server provider to help you with the issue.

Comment: Download and delete the `.htaccess` file and check.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () admin-ajax.php